# Algebra finite over a subalgebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm afraid my question is quite stupid, but I can't find the definition I need: given $A$ a graded algebra, i would like to know what does it mean that $A$ is "finite" over a sub-algebra.

In particular in my case of interest $A$ is not generated in degree 1 but "is finite" over the sub-algebra generated by elements of degree 1.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know what it means that for example $\mathbb{C}$ is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yes of course, $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}\oplus i\mathbb{R}$. So you're saying "finite" is the same as "finite dimensional" over a sub-algebra?

Comment: Yes, but I think that it whold be safer if you give more information. For example I think you refering to group-grading of an algebra, what do you mean by "$A$ is not generated in degree $1$"? $1$ is the unit of the group and you mean that $A$ is finite over $A_1$?

Comment: no, it means that $A$ is not generated by the elements of degree 1, given a grading as in the algebra of polynomials

Comment: I believe finite in these cases usually means finite as a module, that is, finitely generated as a module.  So, there is a sub-algebra $B\subset A$ such that $A$ is a finitely generated module over $B$.  Note this is finitely-generated as a module, not as an algebra ( the difference between $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]$ over $\mathbb{R}$ )

Comment: Again, who is $1$? you are talking about a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading? is $1$ is the unit of a group $G$?

Comment: it is a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading

Comment: So, an example of what you're talking about would be $\mathbb{Z}[x,y^2]/(y^4)$?